# How can i select the comitted files in a post-receive hook in git?

Tags: git, push, githooks, git-post-receive

I need to get the file names, which are comitted withhin the post-receive hook.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
   /* If updated-file == "myFile", then do a specific task */
done
```

How can i get a reference to the changed files?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution to get the list of changed files.

```
git diff --name-only $oldrev $newrev
```